# Square brackets issues in Excel/VBA/Onedrive?

Tags: excel, vba, onedrive

Although I can rename Excel-Files to a name that includes square brackets (which opens fine). I can not save a newly created file within Excel using square brackets in the filename.

Unfortunately `ThisWorkbook.Name` converts square brackets into round brackets directly. Is there a way to avoid this or a good way to find out if square brackets have been used within the file name (so I know that the conversion took place)?

Comment: Looks like `Thisworkbook.FullName` still has the square brackets.

Comment: I did not check this, thank you...  feel free to post it as an answer. Is this a common issue?

Comment: I'm quite irritated by Excel not allowing one to save Excel files with filenames (or into folders) containing square brackets (as the first character). It's a serious limitation (bug) in Excel. The reason that it won't allow this, is because Excel uses square brackets when referencing a resource (cell(s)) in another file/workbook. [link](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-reference-another-sheet-workbook/#:~:text=%5BWorkbook_name%5DSheet_name!Cell_address)

Why limit me from saving a file to a folder starting with a "[" if I'm not planning to use this 'referencing' feature?

Answer (score 1):

`ThisWorkbook.FullName` should still have the brackets in the file name.

For a file saved *locally*, you could `Split` the full name on the path separator and use `InStr` to check if there's a bracket in the last element.

```
Dim s
s = Split(ThisWorkbook.FullName, Application.PathSeparator)

fileName = s(UBound(s))

If InStr(fileName, "[") > 0 Or InStr(fileName, "]") > 0 Then
    ' do whatever
End If
```

Another option (in my opinion, more robust) is to use `FileSystemObject.GetFileName` and still use `InStr` to check for the existence of a bracket. (Make sure to add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime under *Tools* > *References*.)

```
Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

Dim fileName As String
fileName = FSO.GetFileName(ThisWorkbook.FullName)

If InStr(fileName, "[") > 0 Or InStr(fileName, "]") > 0 Then
    ' do whatever
End If
```